# Timer EJB 3.1 + Thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, ejb, schedule

Good Morning. I need to implement an application that every x minutes starts n tasks and each task writes on a MySQL table. I thought I'd fix it using:

1. EJB Timer
2. JPA for writing on DB
3. Executors.newFixedThreadPool for task management

This is my solution. The following class is the Timer EJB:

```java
@Singleton
public class MyTimerService {

   @EJB
   private WorkerPool worker;

   @Schedule(second="*", minute="*/3",hour="*", persistent=false)
   public void doWork(){
      worker.execute();
   }
}
```

This is the Executor implementation:

```java
public class ThreadExecutor implements Executor{

    @Asynchronous
    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        executor.execute(command);
    }
  }
```

and finish, Class to run Thread:

```java
@Stateless
public class WorkerPool {

   @EJB
   private Executor executor;

   @EJB(name = "Dao")
   private IDao dao;

   public void execute()  {

        try {
           List<Object> info = dao.readTable();
            if (info.size() > 0) {
               for (int i = 0; i < info.size(); i++) {
                   Object temp = info.get(i);
                   Runnable worker = new WorkerThread(temp, dao);
                   executor.execute(worker);
               }
               Thread.sleep(30000);
           }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I deploy my application server Glassfish. This is the error:

```java
[2015-07-28T17:06:53.995+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [AS-EJB-00056]     [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=186 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool12] [timeMillis: 1438096013995] [levelValue: 900] [[
  A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB BetFinderTimerService, method: public void com.surebetfinder.timer.BetFinderTimerService.doWork()]]

[2015-07-28T17:06:53.996+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=186 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool12] [timeMillis: 1438096013996] [levelValue: 900] [[

javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:435)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2579)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1971)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy296.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.surebetfinder.logic.processi.__EJB31_Generated__WorkerPool__Intf____Bean__.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.surebetfinder.timer.BetFinderTimerService.doWork(BetFinderTimerService.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundTimeout(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.callEJBTimeout(BaseContainer.java:4051)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.deliverTimeout(EJBTimerService.java:1199)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.access$000(EJBTimerService.java:89)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService$TaskExpiredWork.run(EJBTimerService.java:1919)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:700)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:246)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:430)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:514)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:97)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:698)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=com.surebetfinder.logic.processi.WorkerPool/executor,Remote 3.x interface =java.util.concurrent.Executor,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=java.util.concurrent.Executor,refType=Session into class com.surebetfinder.logic.processi.WorkerPool: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.surebetfinder.logic.processi.WorkerPool/executor' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:175)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.StatelessSessionBeanInjector.inject(StatelessSessionBeanInjector.java:58)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ejb.SessionBeanInjectionTarget.inject(SessionBeanInjectionTarget.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.injectEJBInstance(JCDIServiceImpl.java:257)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.injectEjbInstance(BaseContainer.java:1748)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:475)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=com.surebetfinder.logic.processi.WorkerPool/executor,Remote 3.x interface =java.util.concurrent.Executor,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=java.util.concurrent.Executor,refType=Session into class com.surebetfinder.logic.processi.WorkerPool: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.surebetfinder.logic.processi.WorkerPool/executor' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:740)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:507)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:165)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.surebetfinder.logic.processi.WorkerPool/executor' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=com.surebetfinder.logic.processi.WorkerPool/executor,Remote 3.x interface =java.util.concurrent.Executor,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=java.util.concurrent.Executor,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'java.util.concurrent.Executor#java.util.concurrent.Executor' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java.util.concurrent.Executor#java.util.concurrent.Executor' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java.util.concurrent.Executor#java.util.concurrent.Executor not found]]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:636)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=com.surebetfinder.logic.processi.WorkerPool/executor,Remote 3.x interface =java.util.concurrent.Executor,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=java.util.concurrent.Executor,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'java.util.concurrent.Executor#java.util.concurrent.Executor' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java.util.concurrent.Executor#java.util.concurrent.Executor' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java.util.concurrent.Executor#java.util.concurrent.Executor not found]]
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:188)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1015)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java.util.concurrent.Executor#java.util.concurrent.Executor' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java.util.concurrent.Executor#java.util.concurrent.Executor not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:183)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java.util.concurrent.Executor#java.util.concurrent.Executor not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
    ... 73 more
]]
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: @EJB  private Executor executor; (Executor is not en EJB)

Answer (score 0):

As Gabriel says, when you write

```
   @EJB
   private Executor executor;
```

you're telling the container than `Executor` is an EJB local or remote interface, and the container is failing to look this interface up in JNDI.

Try this:

```
   @EJB
   private ThreadExecutor executor;
```

That requests the "no interface" view of the bean instead.  Alternatively, you could write your own interface to `ThreadExecutor`.

(Aside: Strictly speaking, this behaviour is governed by section 4.9.7-4.9.8 of the EJB 3.1 spec, and I don't think you've broken any of the rules it lays out, so this may be incorrect behaviour from Glassfish?)

That said, I think your `ThreadExecutor` implementation asynchronously creates a thread pool and spins off a thread to perform the work, which I think is superfluous.  Why not just make `WorkerThread` into an EJB with an `@Asynchronous` method?